# differents between WiFi.mode() and wifi_set_opmode()?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

What's the difference between `WiFi.mode()` and `wifi set opmode()` on esp8266?

Comment: For clarity, you might want to provide links to the docs for these areas.

Comment: i know. But docs haven't details about this!

Comment: take a look : https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/readme.html

Comment: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/2c-esp8266_non_os_sdk_api_reference_en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WiFi.mode()` is a function of the esp8266 Arduino WiFi library. `wifi_set_opmode()` is a function of the Espressif SDK.
The Arduino library wraps the C SDK function into Arduino API implementation C++ classes.

The implementation of the `WiFi.getMode()` function:

```
WiFiMode_t ESP8266WiFiGenericClass::getMode() {
    return (WiFiMode_t) wifi_get_opmode();
}
```

The implementation of the setter `WiFi.mode(mode)` has some additional logic but at the end it calls `wifi_set_opmode(mode);`